# Как связать contenteditable блок с переменной (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как связать блок с `contenteditable` с переменной используя `vue`?

Answer (score 7):

```js
Vue.component('editable',{
  template:'<div contenteditable="true" @input="update"></div>',
  props:['content'],
  mounted:function(){
    this.$el.innerText = this.content;
  },
  methods:{
    update:function(event){
      this.$emit('update',event.target.innerText);
    }
  }
})

var example = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    text:"This text is editable!"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <editable :content="text" @update="text = $event"></editable>
  <div>
    <pre>{{$data |json }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/supraniti/pen/Lypobx

Answer (score 1):

Можно обойтись без компонента:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#test', 
  data: { content: '' }, 
  methods: {
    onCeChange: function () { this.content = this.$refs.ce.textContent; }
  }, 
  watch: {
    content: function (val) {
      this.$refs.ce.textContent = val; 
      console.clear(); 
      console.log('this.content: ' + val); 
    }
  }, 
  mounted: function () { this.onCeChange(); }
});
```

```css
[contenteditable] { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script> 

<div id="test">
  <div ref="ce" @input="onCeChange" contenteditable>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Принцип прост: слушаем событие `input` на элементе, и (для двусторонней связи) отслеживаем изменение свойства через `watch`.

---

Более грамотный подход с использованием вычисляемого свойства:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#test', 
  computed: {
    content: {
      cache: false,
      get: function () { return this.$refs.ce.textContent; }, 
      set: function (val) { this.$refs.ce.textContent = val; }
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
    onCeChange: function () {
      console.clear(); 
      console.log('this.content: ' + this.content); 
    }
  }, 
  mounted: function () { this.onCeChange(); }
});
```

```css
[contenteditable] { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script> 

<div id="test">
  <div ref="ce" @input="onCeChange" contenteditable>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```